# Make sticky sidebar stop scrolling when it reaches the footer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I've created a sticky sidebar for my blog, but now I need the sticky element to stop scrolling when I reach the footer. The reason is because the sidebar is overlapping the elements in the footer. How can I solve this?

Working fiddle with overlapping problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/j7x5hLy3/

This is EXACTLY what I'm trying to achieve:

https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/examples/basic.html

Look what happens when the sidebar reaches the bottom. I AM NOT TRYING TO USE Z-INDEX. I'm saying this because in some other questions people are posting "solutions" that uses z-index. I'm not trying to hide anything, I'm trying to make it stop scrolling when it reaches the footer.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
  function isScrolledTo(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //num of pixels hidden above current screen
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top; //num of pixels above the elem
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemTop <= docViewTop));
  }

  var catcher = $('#bannernormal');
  var sticky = $('#bannerfixo');

  if ($(window).width() >= 100) {               
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if (isScrolledTo(sticky)) {
        sticky.css('position', 'fixed');
        sticky.css('top', '0px');
      } 
      var stopHeight = catcher.offset().top + catcher.height();
      if (stopHeight > sticky.offset().top) {
        sticky.css('position', 'absolute');
        sticky.css('top', stopHeight);
      }
    });
        
  } else {
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
#bannernormal {
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
}

#bannerfixo {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
}

#sidebar {
  float: left;
}

#content {
  float: right;
}

#footer {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Content <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="bannernormal">
    This is the "catcher" <code>div</code>
  </div>
  <div id="bannerfixo" style="position: absolute; top: 413px;">
    This is the "sticky" <code>div</code>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">Everything should stop before this part.

  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>
  1010101010101011010<br/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In an effort to keep it simple, here are three nested divs.
The root div represents the root of you document (usually `<body`)
The content can be any div, as long as it has `position: relative`

The div `<div id="relativeTop">` should have `position: absolute`. `relativeTop` will now position itself inside the parent, but you can position it explicitly using top, right, bottom and left. If the parent is not `relative`, it's children will be free to leave it's bounds and therefor will position it's children relative to the window instead.

In javascript, I listen to the scroll event

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
```

This is were you can set the top or bottom value.
Look at the check:

```
if (window.scrollY + rect.height > parentRect.height) {
```

If true, you'll know the div would en up outside of the parent, and you can set `top: 0px` to have it stick to the bottom of it's parent.

Otherwise, you set the top value to the scroll position of the document:

```
el.style.top = window.scrollY + "px";
```

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  const el = document.getElementById("relativeTop");
  const parent = el.parentNode;
  
  const parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  if (window.scrollY + rect.height > parentRect.height) {
    el.style.bottom = "0px";
  } else {
    el.style.top = window.scrollY + "px";
  }
});
```

```css
#body {
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
  height: 1500px;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 2000px;
}
#relativeTop {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="relativeTop">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I try to use your code, the console is throwing an error at the "document.addEventListener". `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>`

Comment: Do you have this div on your page: `<div id="relativeTop">`? `document.getElementById("relativeTop");` returns null if it can't find the element, that's why `const el` is null and null.parentNode doesn't exist :)

Comment: I have to wonder though, K_Hs' answer is perfect and you should be able to make it work in a lot of scenarios if you're willing to work with flexbox: `display: flex`

Comment: "document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {" is also returning a syntax error in the editor.

Comment: I've used "document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {" instead, is it correct?

Comment: `function(e) {}` works too. Are you using the old Internet Explorer by any chance? I'm guessing you're receiving an error for arrow functions: `() => { /* ... */ }` which was introduced in ECMAScript 2015. Did you manage to solve the `Cannot read properties of null` error? Internet explorer also has issues with `parentNode` in some cases. If you're developing for internet explorer, I'd suggest you choose another browser... literally any other browser :)

Comment: I managed to fix the syntax error, I didn't try with Internet Explorer, but it worked with Brave browser. The problem is what when I try to make it work in my website, it won't work, my html structure is different.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 180px;
  height: 160px;
  background: green;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.normal {
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sticky {
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
}

.footer {
  background: pink;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <div class="sidebar normal section">
        Normal
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar sticky section">
        Sticky
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/> Content
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/> Content
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/> Content
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/> Content
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/> Content
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/> Content
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/> Content
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/> Content
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/> Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer section">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution but you might want to add some explanation as to why this appraoch works the way it does.

Comment: This won't work as it should. CSS is unable to achieve what I need.